# how to not rendering back to homepage when in login form?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, single-page-application

I have some problem in Single Page application , when I rendering to login form , and when I refresh my page, it return  to homepage again, how to block the page to stay in login form  when when it is refreshed ?

this is my homepage

```
<template id="" v-if="page.homepage">
      <div class="container ">
       <h1> Homepage </h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

my login:

```
  <template id="" v-if="page.login">
              <div class="container ">
               <h1> Login </h1>
          </div>
        </template>
```

and my method is

```
loginButton(){
   this.page.homepage = false
   this.page.login = true
}
```

when I try to refresh it, and keep to back to homepage, I really get stuck from yesterday for this :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use vue-router and [router guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html)

For example using beforeEach:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const authenticated = !!localStorage.getItem('token')

  if (['login'].includes(to.name) && authenticated) {
    next({ path: 'home' })
  } else if (['home'].includes(to.name) && !authenticated) {
    next({ path: '/login' })
  } else {
    next()
  }

})
```

**Note** that in the above example I have used a stored token to indicate if user is logged or not

Comment: I don't use router yet, should it work ? because I am on Single Page Application , how about if we don't use vue-router?

Comment: Yup vue router can totally be used in Single Page Application.

Comment: so is that impossible if we don't use vue router to handle for my case??

Comment: Of course it is possible. But as far as I know, in all single page applications (not just hello word apps) you'll need a router navigation.

Comment: If still want to handle this using v-if, v-else then just store in a variable the state of the user (logged or not). And use v-if="logged" -> show homepage, v-else show login

Comment: I did like this, but when I refresh , it back to homepage , the code is same like I said above

Comment: It is not the right thing to handle everything with v-if v-else. Vue Router is a great package. As solution, I suggest using it.